# How to add php pages with ajax request to another php in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I have two php files-
index.php
ajax.php

The index.php file contains html, javascript and css along with bootstrap and jquery library.

These are my previous website pages, which are stand-alone, single page website.

How can I add these to a wordpress site so that when the user visits a link, it shows content of index.php and from index.php, the jquery search to ajax.php is performed?

I tried making custom templates and created a page with it, but it does not search for ajax.php file for the ajax requests.

How can I do it? I am a developer myself, I understand PHP, but not the wordpress cms.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches. You can either change index.php to another file, say, "search.php", and it will co-exist with Wordpress and everything will work.

Or, you can "transplant" your index.php into the Wordpress eco-system:

1. create a "page" in wordpress so that you'll have a container.
2. in "functions.php", create a custom shortcode with the add_shortcode function.
   (you could create a plugin as part of the theme so that when you upgrade Wordpress your changes stay compatible, but for now you can just change functions.php)
3. in the content of the new page, use the shortcode.

You can move the jQuery code, HTML markups, etc. into the definition of the shortcode. You might run into some styling collisions but for the most part it should work.

Comment: I wanted the url of the page to be like regular wordpress url, if I add the php file, the url does not match in that case.

Comment: You can add a rewrite rule on the server level and map to the php file transparently